# How can I search for or find text within a web page on the android browser?

Tags: browser

How can I search for or find text within a web page on the android browser?

Answer (score 8):

`(Menu button) More -> Find on page`.

Comment: That feature is broken. On guessing that's why they posted. It just highlights the text; but doesn't actually take you to where it is. Also the next previous buttons are also broken. Basically useless.