# Find text within web page from Samsung Internet browser

Tags: search, samsung-internet-browser

Similar to [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/9263/how-can-i-search-for-or-find-text-within-a-web-page-on-the-android-browser), but for the Samsung Internet Browser (which is opened from the Google app).

As is the case with PC desktop Chrome, using the never-fail `CTRL-F` and `F3` combination does yield the hit count in the search box along with the highlighted hits in the right-hand scrollbar. On the tablet, however, most of the resulting page gets covered by a new layer of white nothing over it, which cannot be removed, unless it is then closed, upon which the search items are lost.

As to the alternative, some suggestions directed us to click on the Google "*Home*" area to acquire the search bar. Somehow, the device does not present as a candidate for Google Home, there may yet be another way to find text on a web page in the Samsung Internet browser.

Comment: A screen shot (may be with added annotations from you) of the described situation would make it easier to understand what you are talking about.

Comment: Is your question about Chrome for PC?

Comment: @Robert: Will try. Reddy: It applies to what is launched from the "Google" icon adjacent by default to the "Chrome" icon in the "Google" collection of icons found in the S10 galaxy tablet "desktop" area.

Comment: I tried to clarify the issue because while there's "Google" app, it's not usually called "Google Browser". However. Google may use another browser to open the web page (e.g. [Chrome Custom Tabs](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/145745/44325) if there's a "Powered by Chrome" text and "Open in Chrome" option in the menu), so a screenshot might really help.

Comment: After testing a little bit, it might actually be about "finding text within web page from *Chrome for Android*" because the behavior is similar to the one described in the question, but some clarifications would help much more.

Comment: @AndrewT. , apologies for the confusion- have some difficulty pulling screenshots off this device, however on the browser page launched by the Google search, (the page where the text is sought) there is a menu option "Open in Samsung Internet." So it may not be Chrome, thus the issue in the linked question at the top of the OP may actually be the case here.